# How can I create a violin plot in Google Spreadsheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-charts

How can I create a violin plot in Google Spreadsheets?

Example of violin plot:

[image]

Comment: Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: 3 years later, your question still pops up first. Not tested yet, but I just wanted to point out that there are a few other answers now, such as here: https://zebrabi.com/advanced-guide/how-to-customize-violin-plot-in-google-sheets/